# How to retrieve the groups of an object?

Tags: python, objects, groups

How to get all of the groups an object is assigned to in Blender Python?

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects: # All objects
    # TODO: Retrieve the groups of obj.
```

Comment: Do you mean all the groups that an object is in? - or all the dupligroup objects that the object instances? Please try be more precise with questions.

Comment: I mean all the groups that an object is in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself: Use `obj.users_group`, e.g.

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects: # All objects
    for group in obj.users_group: # All groups
        # Do something, e.g. use group.name to find specific groups.
```